# Laravel app won't update database connection settings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel app, been using a specific set of database settings for a very long time, now I uploaded the whole application to CPanel and trying to change both the .env and .env.example files but still, when I look at the error logs uses the old database details, am stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure to clear all caches before deploying

Comment: You could try to run the command `php artisan cache:clear` whit in the projects folder

Comment: am actually resorting to putting the entire thing in htdocs the same way I would put it in CPanel and debug it from there until it works, will let you know on any issues I will need help with after I try out all your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

After cracking and scratching my head several times, I actually used these laravel CLI commands

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

Now everything is working okay. Of course I took it offline first and used htdocs until it worked okay then uploaded the latest files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using the latest laravel framework 5.4 but you can try the following:

**Clearing the config cache with this artisan command**

php artisan config:clear

**Checking the environment**

php artisan env

With this command you can make sure that you are running under the correct environment. If you are using specific .env file such as ".env.local" or ".env.dev" etc.

Make sure there's nothing wrong with your dbms installation and try to connect to another blank db.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: current environment is local, application is now in my htdocs, changed the settings but still reading the old settings